# Having difficulty parsing a response from an API call

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm trying to parse the response object from an API call, but having some difficulty.

First, I parsed the returned JSON with following:

```swift
let responseObject = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)) as? [String: Any]
if let result = responseObject["result"] {
  print(result)
}
```

Then, when I log the result, following is what I get:

```
{
    "_links" =     {
        next = "/api/3/action/datastore_search?limit=50&id=22f223e7-73f7-4842-935c-80a0ba5c3e5b&offset=50";
        start = "/api/3/action/datastore_search?limit=50&id=22f223e7-73f7-4842-935c-80a0ba5c3e5b";
    };
    fields =     (
                {
            id = "_id";
            type = int;
        },
                {
            id = package;
            info =             {
                label = "";
                notes = "Unique, normalized, name of dataset.
                "type_override" = "";
            };
            type = text;
        }
    )
}
```

I tried parsing it again:

```swift
let finalResult = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: result)) as? [String: Any]
```

But, I get the following error:

> No exact matches in call to class method 'jsonObject'

**Update**

```swift
if let result = responseObject["result"] as? [String: Any] {
    if let finalResult = result["records"] {
        print(finalResult)
    }
}
```

When I log this, I get the following:

```
(
        {
        "_id" = 186;
        accessibility = 1;
        completeness = "0.6899999999999999";
        freshness = "0.5";
        grade = Silver;
        "grade_norm" = Silver;
        metadata = "0.84";
        package = "air-conditioned-and-cool-spaces-heat-relief-network";
        "recorded_at" = "2019-12-17T20:24:09";
        score = "0.78";
        "score_norm" = "0.76";
        usability = "0.86";
        version = "v0.1.0";
    },
        {
        "_id" = 187;
        accessibility = 1;
        completeness = 1;
        freshness = 0;
        grade = Bronze;
        "grade_norm" = Bronze;
        metadata = "0.25";
        package = "air-conditioned-public-places-cooling-centres";
        "recorded_at" = "2019-12-17T20:24:09";
        score = "0.54";
        "score_norm" = "0.31";
        usability = "0.85";
        version = "v0.1.0";
    },
)
```

When I tried to iterate this:

```swift
for (key, value) in finalResult {
    print("key", key)
    print("value", value)
}
```

I get the following error:

> Tuple pattern cannot match values of none-tuple type

Comment: What are you trying to do with `finalResult`?  Your result is already the json object

Comment: @valosip I want to extract individual fields and display them on the user interface.

Comment: Your `result` is shown in the format of `NSDictionary`. You should not re-decode it, but should cast it to `[String: Any]` and use it as a Swift Dictionary.

Comment: @OOPer Thanks. I didn't realize it was a dictionary. I updated the question (ignore the data difference. I had truncated it for brevity)

Comment: `result["records"]` is an `NSArray` containing `NSDictionary`. You need to cast your new `finalResult` to `[[String: Any]]`.

Comment: Please post your working code as an answer by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @OOPer, I was able to parse it as a dictionary:

```swift
if let result = responseObject["result"] as? [String: Any] {
    if let finalResult = result["records"] as? [[String: Any]] {
        finalResult.forEach { (catalogue) in
            if let package = catalogue["package"] as? String {
            }
        }
    }
}
```